# Get next and previous nodeType

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<body>Testing1<span id="t1" style="background-color: green;">Testing2</span>Testing3</body>
```

When I try the following:

```
alert(window.jQuery('#t1').prev().nodeType); // undefined - tried get(0) as well

alert(window.jQuery('#t1').get(0).nodeType); // 1

alert(window.jQuery('#t1').next().nodeType); // undefined
```

Why is it that I get undefined when I try to get the node type of the previous and next text elements?

The weird thing is if I put a `b` tag before the span, the `prev().get(0).nodeType` returns a `1` does that mean text nodes and comments are undetectable??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `prev` and `next` return jQuery objects, not DOM elements. You will have to use `get` again:

```
alert(window.jQuery('#t1').next().get(0).nodeType);
```

Note that you can alternatively use array syntax to get the underlying DOM element at the specified index:

```
alert(window.jQuery('#t1').next()[0].nodeType);
```

**Edit**

Just re-read your question and saw that you've already tried that. You are right in thinking that `prev` and `next` will not get text or comment nodes. They will only get elements.

The text node that precedes `#t1` is not an element, so `prev` will not return anything (there are no sibling elements preceding or following `#t1`).

You could do this:

```
alert(window.jQuery('#t1').get(0).previousSibling.nodeType); //3
alert(window.jQuery('#t1').get(0).nextSibling.nodeType); //3
```

But I'm not entirely sure of the browser compatibility of those.

Comment: the strange thing is I get undefined reported by firebug at the `get(0)` point - also see update in question.

Comment: I see and whats even more strange is that when I loop through all spans using jQuery and I do this `this.nextSibling` within the loop. I can get the nodeType! What's going on? Maybe there is another way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: That's because in the loop `this` will be a reference to a DOM element, not a jQuery object. See my new edit for a possible solution!

Comment: Awesome - this is only need for testing on Firefox and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use plain js:

```
alert(document.getElementById('t1').previousSibling.nodeType);
alert(document.getElementById('t1').nextSibling.nodeType);
```

of course you should check that getElementById returns an element and that there is a next/previousSibling before trying to get its nodeType.